# Arm gcc 4.8.2 tool chain cannot relocate unimplemented reloc R_ARM_TLS_CALL

Tags: gcc, arm, ld, thread-local-storage

I am cross compiling chrome sources with ARM. 
While linking chromedriver, i am getting the following error:

```
libstdc++.a(eh_globals.o): unsupported reloc 91 against local symbol
eh_globals.cc:58: error: cannot relocate unimplemented reloc R_ARM_TLS_CALL in object file
```

I am compiling with:

```
"-march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -funsafe-math-optimizations"
```

CPU info gives

```
Features        : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls
```

It says it has TLS register.

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I guess it is not much of help, but about 2 years ago I had a similar error due to optimization flags (such as the -funsafe-math-optimizations) which resultet in alignment problems (I neede a flag to guarantee that, which I cannot remember right now) throwing an error which was similar. Which I would never have guessed.

Comment: What _linker_ are you using? The fact that that apparently doesn't support a certain relocation type matters infinitely more than whether the CPU of a target device which won't be running an un-linked executable has hardware TLS registers or not...

Comment: @Notlikethat - Thanks for the hint. Every thing looked fine as it was passing arm-linux-g++ for linking. But later when I really noticed that it was taking LD in another path, because of which it was giving error.